# как можно сделать стиль overflow: hidden для body когда открывается popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, body

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup__area {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.popup__body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__body {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}

.popup__content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__content {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12.8rem;
  top: 8rem;
  background: url(../icons/close.svg) center center/contain no-repeat;
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .popup__close {
    right: 1.5rem;
    top: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.popup__img {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 479.98px) {
  .popup__img {
    zoom: 142%;
  }
}

.popup__text {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popup__text h3 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: -0.112rem;
  max-width: 51.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__text h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__text h3 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .popup__text h3 {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
  }
}

.popup__text>p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: -0.036rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__text>p {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.popup__form {
  max-width: 55.4rem;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__form {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.popup__form input,
.popup__form label {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: -0.032rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.6rem 1rem;
}

.popup__form input {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #333;
}

.popup__form input:focus-visible,
.popup__form input:focus {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #1F4D38;
}

.popup__form label {
  color: #808080;
}

.popup__form>input:not:first-child {
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
}

.popup__form button {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  max-width: 18rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup__inputs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3.2rem !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__inputs {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.popup__checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__checkbox {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.popup__checkbox a {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.popup__checkbox a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.popup__checkbox a:active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup__btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-top: 8.9rem;
  gap: 1.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__btn {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.popup__btn button {
  align-self: normal;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__btn button {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.popup__form-consult>div+div {
  margin-top: 3.1rem;
}

.popup__form-consult a {
  max-width: 18rem;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__form-consult a {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 4.4rem;
  }
}

.popup__form-consult-btn {
  margin-top: 7rem !important;
}

.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-wrapper select {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-wrapper input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
.input-wrapper input:focus+label {
  bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.popup:target {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header__links links">
  <li>
    <a href="#popup__consult" class="text-1">For Providers</a>
    <div class="decor-line"></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="popup__consult" class="popup">
  <a href="#!" class="popup__area"></a>
  <div class="popup__body justify-content-flex-end">
    <a href="#close__popup" class="popup__close close-2"></a>
    <div class="popup__content w-5 h-1">
      <div class="popup__text w-7">
        <h3 class="popup__title w-6">Request Consultation</h3>
        <p>Answer a few questions so the provider can get in touch</p>
        <form class="popup__form popup__form-consult w-7" action="#!">
          <div class="popup__inputs">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="name" required placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
              <label for="name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="last" required placeholder="">
              <label for="last">Last Name</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popup__inputs">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper w-8">
              <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
              <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="choice">
            <p>Payment type</p>
            <div class="checkbox radio">
              <label>
                                        <input type="radio" checked name="coding-notes" class="checkbox__real">
                                        <span class="checkbox__custom checkbox__custom_1">Insurance</span>
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox radio radio_2">
              <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="coding-notes" class="checkbox__real">
                                        <span class="checkbox__custom">Out of Pocket</span>
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popup__inputs">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="">
              <label for="code">City or ZIP code</label>
            </div>
            <div class="select" tabindex="1">
              <div class="custom-select">
                <select id="select-2">
                  <option value="0">Virtual or In-person</option>
                  <option value="1">Virtual</option>
                  <option value="2">In-person</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popup__inputs flex-direction-column">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="">
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="What brings you here?" name="info">
          </div>
          <div class="popup__btn popup__form-consult-btn">
            <a href="#close__popup" class="btn btn-4">Cancel</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-3">
                                    Submit
                                    <span class="decor-ball-arrow color-3"><img class="arrow-white"
                                            src="icons/arrow-white.svg" alt="arrow-white"></span>
                                </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужен javascript. Хотя, можно и на CSS решить, но не во всех браузерах будет работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить на CSS:

```css
body:has(.popup:target) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Когда в `body` присутствует `.popup:target`, к body будет применяться `overflow: hidden`
Можно решить и на JS кроссбраузерно, но, думаю, вы не заботитесь о кроссбраузерности

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup__area {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.popup__body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__body {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}

.popup__content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__content {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12.8rem;
  top: 8rem;
  background: url(../icons/close.svg) center center/contain no-repeat;
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .popup__close {
    right: 1.5rem;
    top: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.popup__img {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 479.98px) {
  .popup__img {
    zoom: 142%;
  }
}

.popup__text {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popup__text h3 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: -0.112rem;
  max-width: 51.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__text h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__text h3 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .popup__text h3 {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
  }
}

.popup__text>p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: -0.036rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__text>p {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.popup__form {
  max-width: 55.4rem;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .popup__form {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.popup__form input,
.popup__form label {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: -0.032rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.6rem 1rem;
}

.popup__form input {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #333;
}

.popup__form input:focus-visible,
.popup__form input:focus {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #1F4D38;
}

.popup__form label {
  color: #808080;
}

.popup__form>input:not:first-child {
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
}

.popup__form button {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  max-width: 18rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup__inputs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3.2rem !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__inputs {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.popup__checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__checkbox {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.popup__checkbox a {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.popup__checkbox a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.popup__checkbox a:active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup__btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-top: 8.9rem;
  gap: 1.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__btn {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.popup__btn button {
  align-self: normal;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__btn button {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.popup__form-consult>div+div {
  margin-top: 3.1rem;
}

.popup__form-consult a {
  max-width: 18rem;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479.98px) {
  .popup__form-consult a {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 4.4rem;
  }
}

.popup__form-consult-btn {
  margin-top: 7rem !important;
}

.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-wrapper select {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-wrapper input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
.input-wrapper input:focus+label {
  bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.popup:target {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible;
}

body:has(.popup:target) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header__links links">
  <li>
    <a href="#popup__consult" class="text-1">For Providers</a>
    <div class="decor-line"></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="popup__consult" class="popup">
  <a href="#!" class="popup__area"></a>
  <div class="popup__body justify-content-flex-end">
    <a href="#close__popup" class="popup__close close-2"></a>
    <div class="popup__content w-5 h-1">
      <div class="popup__text w-7">
        <h3 class="popup__title w-6">Request Consultation</h3>
        <p>Answer a few questions so the provider can get in touch</p>
        <form class="popup__form popup__form-consult w-7" action="#!">
          <div class="popup__inputs">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="name" required placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
              <label for="name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="last" required placeholder="">
              <label for="last">Last Name</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popup__inputs">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper w-8">
              <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
              <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="choice">
            <p>Payment type</p>
            <div class="checkbox radio">
              <label>
                                        <input type="radio" checked name="coding-notes" class="checkbox__real">
                                        <span class="checkbox__custom checkbox__custom_1">Insurance</span>
                                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox radio radio_2">
              <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="coding-notes" class="checkbox__real">
                                        <span class="checkbox__custom">Out of Pocket</span>
                                    </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popup__inputs">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="">
              <label for="code">City or ZIP code</label>
            </div>
            <div class="select" tabindex="1">
              <div class="custom-select">
                <select id="select-2">
                  <option value="0">Virtual or In-person</option>
                  <option value="1">Virtual</option>
                  <option value="2">In-person</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popup__inputs flex-direction-column">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="">
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="What brings you here?" name="info">
          </div>
          <div class="popup__btn popup__form-consult-btn">
            <a href="#close__popup" class="btn btn-4">Cancel</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-3">
                                    Submit
                                    <span class="decor-ball-arrow color-3"><img class="arrow-white"
                                            src="icons/arrow-white.svg" alt="arrow-white"></span>
                                </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```